How to display acf fields in Woocommerce product editor (wp-admin)?
ACF fields are not displayed on the product editor page. I went to the "All products" page, clicked "edit" in the product options and went to the page. In the "Main" tab, I scrolled down and did not see any ACF fields to add data to them.
Version WordPress 6.6.1, Woocommerce 8.7.0, ACF 6.2.2
I created a group of fields and in the settings for the location of the group of fields I specified the following:
"Post Type is equal to Product" ("Тип записи равно товар"):

And that's what I was talking about.
Below, as you can see on the ACF product editor page, the fields are not displayed for data entry:

So what could be the problem?
Here are my ACF fields and display settings:






the solution to this problem was to update Woocommerce to version 9.1.4
Then read the material at this link:
https://developer.woocommerce.com/docs/how-to-fix-outdated-woocommerce-templates

You will need to go to status>system status and scroll to the "Templates" block and see if there are any templates in your current theme that need to be changed/changed their location/content (To do this, you should also go to the "Plugins>plugin editor" section after installing the new version of Woocommerce and see what you need to change in your templates and what to leave unchanged)

After the manipulations done, go to the product editor and, depending on where you set the location of the ACF fields in the ACF settings in the "Presentation" tab, a field for filling in data will be displayed

